# Getting the error "SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_SIGNATURE_TYPE] wrong signature type (_ssl.c:1002)'))" using Python library Requests

Tags: python, http, ssl, python-requests

I'm trying to make a GET request to URL https://si3.ufc.br using Python requests lib:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://si3.ufc.br/', verify=False)

print(r)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='si3.ufc.br', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /sigaa/public/home.jsf (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_SIGNATURE_TYPE] wrong signature type (_ssl.c:1002)')))
```

Already tryed to set parameter "verify" to False, but it didn't change.
Also tryed, as recomended in other answer, to set:

```
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1'
```

But didn't work either.

To other URLs, it's working fine, but i need to access that one.
I expected to get response with status code 200.

Answer (score 1):

For this site, set `AES128-SHA256` cipher:

```py
import ssl

import requests


class TLSAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
        ctx.set_ciphers("AES128-SHA256")
        kwargs["ssl_context"] = ctx
        return super(TLSAdapter, self).init_poolmanager(*args, **kwargs)


url = "https://si3.ufc.br"

with requests.session() as s:
    s.mount("https://", TLSAdapter())
    print(s.get(url))
```

Prints:

```
<Response [200]>
```

---

For future reference: you can go to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=si3.ufc.br and at the end of the page you see **Handshake Simulation** (and ciphers which succeeded - you can try to set these ciphers explicitly in `ssl`):

[image]

Comment: DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0 works too for the cipher.